# Delay the scrolling in a UIScrollView by changing the required finger offset

Tags: ios

I want to make my scrollview less sensitive. This means that I want the user to have to move the finger a bit more before the view starts scrolling. Does anyone knows how to achieve this? I remember seeing a property that would let me set a required number of pixels before a scroll is detected. But it could just be my imagination. Perhaps what is required is to modify the underlying UIPanGestureRecognizer inside the scroll view?

The reason for this is that I am detecting a press on the view, so as long as the user has the finger there a function is constantly running. This function has to have the absolute priority, but the user might want to scroll the view instead, so I am canceling the function by detecting if the scrollview was scrolled. Everything works perfectly, except when the user is moving his hand/arm, his finger "might slip" a little bit, thus canceling the function since the scrollview starts scrolling.

Edit: (to address some of the confusion in the question)

**How do I delay the scrolling in a scrollview by requiring the user to move the finger more before the scrollview starts scrolling?**

Comment: you have a longpress on the scrollview? You should be able to give the longpress the priority over the panrecognizer with the `requireGestureRecognizerToFail:` method or, if you have to decide at runtime the coresponding delegate methods.

Comment: No, I don't have a gesture recognizer for the press. I'm subclassing the scroll view to detect touch events. But that's not the issue. I want to change the offset a finger is required to move before the view starts scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

I write an Answer so i can write code, but i am not entirely sure why you want the finger-offset. Lets assume you have an Area on your scrollview in which the user can longpress. During longpress you want to do some calculating and you do not want the scrollview to move. In my opinion there are two possibilties: Either you want the longpress to cancel if the finger moves a certain amount ("difficult to archive") or you want to supress the scrollview movement as long as the finger is pressed down, no matter what the movement is ("simple to archive").

Simple Solution:

```
- (void)yourUIBuilder {
  ...
  UILongPressGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressChanged:)];
  [recognizer setDelegate:self];
  [recognizer setMinimumPressDuration:0.3];
  [yourScrollView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
}                                                  

- (void)longPressChanged:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    switch (recognizer.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
                        // start your calculations
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
            break;
        default:
                        // stop your calculations
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want the offset to improve the user experience. I'm not using a long press but i guess the behavior would be the same. The user experience changes since I want to make it "harder to scroll" to avoid canceling my other function. However none of the two possibilities you mention are what I am looking for. Think of it in this way instead. How do I delay the scrolling in a scrollview by requiring the user to move the finger more before the scrollview starts scrolling?